# How to verify encryption at host on azure VM

Tags: linux, azure, encryption, linux-kernel, hyper-v

Having gone through the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-enable-host-based-encryption-portal?tabs=azure-cli#prerequisites), I learnt how to enable `encryption at host` for a given VM in a subscription.

Now, I need to know whether the end-to-end encryption as told in the documentation is happening. When I used `ADE`, it was relatively easy to check the encryption status from the VM.

Is this something possible to check from guest VM when `encryption at host` is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-enable-host-based-encryption-portal?tabs=azure-powershell#restrictions), to explore more about the restrictions and supported VMs to enable end-to-end encryption using **encryption at host**.

- I followed the above-mentioned document to enable end-to-end encryption using **encryption at host** using azure portal.

1. **Azure portal**: Select the Cloud Shell icon on the Azure portal.
2. Using the below commands to register and verify the feature for the subscription.

[image]

3. Created VM, Key Vaults and Disk Encryption Set.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

4. Encryption status of Linux VM can be seen as below:

- If we select **Platform managed key (PMK)** in *key management*:
  [image]
- If we select **Customer-managed key (CMK)** in *key management*:
  [image]

**Azure Disk Encryption for Linux VMs:**

1. I have followed the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disk-encryption-linux#enable-encryption-on-an-existing-or-running-linux-vm-using-azure-cli) to enable encryption on Linux VM using azure cli.
   The VM is encrypted and can be seen the status as below:

[image]